AddRectangleSeries occlusion custom addCustoms Tick
I tried to modify the drawing order but couldn't change the custom addCustoms Tick that was obscured by addRectangle Series. I want addCustoms Tick to be on top of Rectangle Series.
This is a picture
I tried to modify the transparency of the setDefaultStyle background color of addRectangleSeries, although it can be achieved, it is not what I want.
I hope addCustoms Tick can be displayed on addRectangle Series.
This is the code I tried.
let axisX = chart
        .getDefaultAxisX()
        .setInterval({ start: 0, end: 20, stopAxisAfter: false });
      let axisY = chart
        .getDefaultAxisY()
        .setInterval({ start: 0, end: 20, stopAxisAfter: false });

      chart
        .addRectangleSeries({
          xAxis: axisX,
          yAxis: axisY,
        })
        .setHighlight(false)
        .setEffect(false)
        .setMouseInteractions(false)
        .setDrawOrder(0)
        .setDefaultStyle((setDefaultStyle) => {
          setDefaultStyle.setFillStyle(
            new SolidFill({
              color: ColorRGBA(229, 239, 253),
            })
          );
        })
        .add({
          x: 10,
          y: 5,
          width: 10,
          height: 1,
        });

      let customTick = axisX
        .addCustomTick(UIElementBuilders.PointableTextBox)
        .setGridStrokeLength(20)
        .setGridStrokeStyle(
          new SolidLine({
            thickness: 2,
            fillStyle: new SolidFill({
              color: ColorRGBA(255, 255, 255),
            }),
          })
        )
        .setValue(11);

